# Change only a specific option with clang-format in C++ source file

Tags: clang-format

I need to change only PointerAlignment with clang-format and leave all the other options unchanged. Is it possible?

I tried the following file:

```
BasedOnStyle: Google
IndentWidth: 4
Language: Cpp
# Force pointers to the type for C++.
DerivePointerAlignment: false
PointerAlignment: Left
```

it changes PointerAlignment, but applies Google style. Also I tried

```
BasedOnStyle: none
```

but it does not work.

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It appears to be possible to use `BasedOnStyle: None`, based on examples I've found ao here
https://github.com/orbs-network/crypto-lib/blob/master/.clang-format
but nothing I do seems to work.

I'm using v9.0.0 (trunk).  Perhaps a bug?

Comment: I've tested all the way back to v6.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_601/final), and still no luck.  Are we misunderstanding or misinterpreting something?  Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: @kowalski5233 No I did not find a way to change only a specific option. As far as I remember, I tried 'None' basic style, but with no success.

Comment: You can't apply a subset of the style options. `BasedOnStyle: None` is equivalent to `DisableFormat: true, SortIncludes: false, SortUsingDeclarations: false`.